# Write R dataframe with column-specific precision

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to **print a data.frame with column-specific number of decimals**.

Consider the following example:

```
df <- data.frame(A = c("R1","R2","R3"), B = rnorm(3), C= rnorm(3))
write.table(format(df, digits=0,nsmall=2,scientific=FALSE),file="...")
```

It prints two decimals for both columns B and C. How can I print say 3 decimals for column B and 4 for column C? As far as I can see the `format(.)` function does not allow that.

I am aware here there is a high risk of duplication, but I can't find a tweak so I take the risk.

Comment: Maybe `formatC(df$B, digits = 3, format = 'f')`?

Comment: You could try `df[-1] <- Map(sprintf, df[-1], fmt = c("%0.3f", "%0.4f"))`

Comment: @Jaap That seems to work:
`df$B <- formatC(df$B, digits = 3, format = 'f')
df$C <- formatC(df$C, digits = 4, format = 'f')
write.table(df,file="...")`